# Unable to access images from images folder in jsp file

Tags: image, jsp

Following is my directory structure of a jsp application. Images are placed in the images folder, but I can't access them though the following code.

Comment: <img class="simple-ss" src="images/1.jpg" >

Comment: open inspect element and check what URL it's making a call to? you can modify it accordingly.

Comment: Ok thanks. I found the solution